# Find the value of expression $^2+^2+^2$ given $++=1$ and $\frac 1x +\frac 1y +\frac 1z=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of expression $$^2+^2+^2$$ given $$++=1$$ and $$\frac 1x +\frac 1y +\frac 1z=0$$

I am sorry I don't really know how to tag this question.

Comment: Simplify the $1/x+1/y+1/z=0$, when is a fraction equal to $0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with symmetric polynomials? The symmetric polynomials of $x,y,z$ are $s_1=x+y+z$, $s_2=xy+yz+zx$ and $s_3=xyz$. A way to solve this problem is to write $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $1/x+1/y+1/z$ using $s_1,s_2,s_3$. Do you see a way of doing that?

Comment: I don't know symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Look up [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: Where are your tries?

Answer (score 7):

HINT: from $x+y+z=1$ we get by squaring
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1-2(xy+yz+zx)$$ and from $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0$$ we obtain $$yz+xz+yz=0$$ thus our searched value is $1$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2xyz\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $x,y,z$ are the roots of a monic, cubic polynomial $p(t)$
$$ p(t) = (t-x)(t-y)(t-z) = t^3-e_1 t^2+e_2 t-e_3. $$
Since $x+y+z=1$ we have $e_1=1$. Similarly, from $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0$ we get $e_2=0$.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x+y+z)^2-2(xy+xz+yz) = e_1^2-e_2$$
then leads to $x^2+y^2+z^2=\color{blue}{1}$.